# Looking for any studies OR anecdotal stories on the usability of lightweight markup languages (like Markdown, MediaWiki or BBCode)

Tags: usability, usability-study

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Markdown Friendly Enough for Non-Technical Users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/is-markdown-friendly-enough-for-non-technical-users)

I need to create a simple markup language (none of the ones out there quite fit the bill). However, I'd really like to be able to leverage the most usable aspects of the languages out there. Are there any usability studies OR do you have any good anecdotes about the ability for laymen to learn and use lightweight markup languages such as Markdown, MediaWiki, or BBCode?

Comment: You might look at the existing questions: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/is-markdown-friendly-enough-for-non-technical-users and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15899/is-markdown-fundamentally-unfriendly-for-most-users

Comment: not really a duplicate since that post only covers markdown. If we omit the anecdotal part, which I think are important, the user was asking for any studies, so it would be fait to have the post open. I can't answer the question since I don't work with them, but I may start a project soon and I'm still deciding between markdown and mediawiki; or a hybrid.